# Async calls in Web Api

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

In asp.net Web API how can I call long running blocking actions asynchronously?

I have a web api controller action that needs to make a relatively (10 seconds, as an example) long running DB call. This seems like a candidate for an asynchronous method. I can offload the long running task onto a new thread, and unblock my asp.net request thread to handle some other requests, so my simplified controller action would look like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    IEnumerable<Thing> things = await Task.Run(() => DoLongDbCall());
    return Ok(things);
}
```

I have encountered a couple of blogs ([this one](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html), for example) that suggest this may not be an optimal way to achieve this in asp.net. The author suggests using `Task.FromResult()` and doing the DB call synchronously, but i cant see how this helps; My request thread is still going to be blocked waiting for the DB call to return.

Comment: All requests already execute on a separate thread so you don't care about blocking unless you want to execute two or more calls in parallel. Calling `await Task.Run` simply *wastes* another thread when you could use the original thread.

Comment: You realise that in this scenario using `async`/`await` really isn't giving you anything?

Comment: ADO.NET *and* EF *do* support asynchronous calls. `DoLongDbCall` should itself be an asynchronous method. In that case, you would be releasing the current thread while waiting for the database *without* using an extra thread to wait

Answer (score 5):

First, consider what happens with a synchronous call:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
  IEnumerable<Thing> things = DoLongDbCall();
  return Ok(things);
}
```

A request comes in, and ASP.NET grabs a thread pool thread to handle the request. This thread invokes the `Get` method, which does the work. One thread pool thread is used during the entire request.

Now, let's walk through what happens in the current code (using `Task.Run`):

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
  IEnumerable<Thing> things = await Task.Run(() => DoLongDbCall());
  return Ok(things);
}
```

A request comes in, and ASP.NET grabs a thread pool thread to handle the request. This thread invokes the `Get` method, which then grabs *another* thread pool thread to do the work and returns the *original* thread pool thread back to the thread pool. One thread pool thread is used during the entire request (and two thread pool threads are used for a very brief period of time).

So, the `Task.Run` code forces an extra thread transition without providing any benefit (the entire point of using `async` on the server side is to free up threads). This is why I recommend against using `Task.Run` (or any other way to run work on the thread pool) on ASP.NET.

A proper asynchronous solution would be to use asynchronous DB calls:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
  IEnumerable<Thing> things = await DoLongDbCallAsync();
  return Ok(things);
}
```

A request comes in, and ASP.NET grabs a thread pool thread to handle the request. This thread invokes the `Get` method, which then starts the asynchronous operation and returns the thread pool thread back to the thread pool. Later, when the db call completes, ASP.NET grabs a thread pool thread to finish the request. For most of the request, *no* thread pool threads are used (one thread pool thread is used for a brief period of time at the beginning and end of the request).

Comment: That makes sense to a degree, but i dont see the difference between `Task.Run(() => LongAction)` and `LongActionAsync`. No matter how many layers of abstraction i put on top of it my 'asynchronosity' is going to require the creation of a new thread at some point?

Comment: @richzilla: No, it won't necessarily require a separate thread. I explain [how `async` can be threadless](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) on my blog.

Comment: This is so well explained, I'm going to award a bounty asap. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

> my request thread is still going to be blocked waiting for the DB call to return.

That's not completely true:

Your request will still wait for the long operation to end, but your thread will be free to process other operations.

You must keep in mind that IIS has a reduced number of available threads (especially if running under non server systems) and freeing one that is not needed is always a good thing.

Moreover, if you have shortage of threads, and if you use `Task.Run`, the asynchronous operation will wait for an available thread, and if you don't release your current one, you'll end up with an horrible deadlock.